# MayTag Front Loader Washer Will Not Fill With Water

Tags: washing-machine

My maytag mhw6000xw0 will not fill with water.  I have replaced the water intake valve, as well as the door lock latch.  After replacing both of these parts the issue still remains.

My question I want to pose is there a way to "bypass" the door lock latch to see if it is faulty?  I used a voltmeter to test and verify that the water intake valve is functioning power wise at it should.

Comment: You should hear (normally in this order), the door lock and then the intake valve click open.  Do you hear any of this happen when the washer starts?  If they never get the signal to activate, it could be a controller problem or the door-closed sensor.

Comment: I hear the door lock, then it will show add garment for a minute or so, then another click, then another click, and the countdown on the washer begins.  After some time it will show an error code that escapes me atm, but it is def not filling with water.  (And yes, I have checked the water lines and pressure to verify those are as they should be)